# SQL Integrity constraint-Parent key not found

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have looked over the internet and their solutions wont fix my problem, hence I'm asking for help here to check if there's mistakes in my coding.

I wanted to create a temporary table populated by other source tables and then implement it into the fact table. I have checked if the data type and the parameter is matching or the sequence of the keys but still it's giving me the error

> "ORA-02291: integrity constraint (SYSTEM.SYS_C007167) violated -
>   parent key not found"

Fact Table:

```
CREATE TABLE DW_ITEMS7364 (
DW_ID int not null,
ManID char(5),
WHID char(5),
STKID char(5),
Profit number,
CONSTRAINT DW_ID PRIMARY KEY (DW_ID),
FOREIGN KEY(ManID) REFERENCES DW_MANUFACTURER7364,
FOREIGN KEY(WHID) REFERENCES DW_WAREHOUSE7364,
FOREIGN KEY(StkID) REFERENCES DW_STOCKITEM7364);


CREATE SEQUENCE seq_items7364 START WITH 101 increment by 1;

CREATE TRIGGER trg_items7364 BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON DW_ITEMS7364
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SELECT seq_items7364.NEXTVAL
  INTO   :new.DW_ID
  FROM   dual;
END;
```

Temporary Table:

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP_TAB7364 AS( SELECT m.ManID, w.WHID, s.STKID, (s.SellingPrice-s.PurchasePrice) AS "Profit"
FROM MANUFACTURER7364 m LEFT OUTER JOIN STOCKITEM7364 s ON s.ManID = m.ManID
RIGHT OUTER JOIN WAREHOUSE7364 w on s.WHID = w.WHID WHERE s.SELLINGPRICE IS NOT NULL AND s.PURCHASEPRICE IS NOT NULL
);
```

These are my source tables:

```
CREATE TABLE MANUFACTURER7364(
ManID char(5),
ManName varchar (25),
CityID char(5) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(ManID),
FOREIGN KEY(CityID) REFERENCES CITY7364);

CREATE TABLE WAREHOUSE7364(
WHID char(5),
MaxNoOfPallets number,
CostPerPallet number,
SecurityLevel char(1),
FreezerFacilities varchar(10),
QuarantineFacilities varchar(10),
CityID char(5) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(WHID),
FOREIGN KEY(CityID) REFERENCES CITY7364);

CREATE TABLE STOCKITEM7364(
StkID char(5),
StkName varchar(20),
SellingPrice number, 
PurchasePrice number,
ManID char(5) NOT NULL,
WHID char(5) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(StkID),
FOREIGN KEY(ManID) REFERENCES MANUFACTURER7364,
FOREIGN KEY(WHID) REFERENCES WAREHOUSE7364);
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, *nothing* of what you posted raises that error.

Additional drawback is the way you chose to create foreign key constraints. If you don't name it, Oracle assigns the name itself and it looks the way you posted it: `SYSTEM.SYS_C007167`.

```
SQL> create table test
  2    (id_dept number,
  3     id_emp  number,
  4     foreign key (id_dept) references dept (deptno),
  5     foreign key (id_emp)  references emp  (empno));

Table created.

SQL> select constraint_name from user_constraints where table_name = 'TEST';

CONSTRAINT_NAME
------------------------------
SYS_C008172
SYS_C008173

SQL>
```

When one of these fails, looking at its name you *have no idea* what went wrong, unless you investigate a little bit more:

```
SQL> select column_name from user_cons_columns where constraint_name = 'SYS_C008173';

COLUMN_NAME
-----------------------    
ID_EMP

SQL>
```

But, if you name the constraint, it is way simpler:

```
SQL> create table test
  2    (id_dept number,
  3     id_emp  number,
  4     constraint fk_test_dept foreign key (id_dept) references dept (deptno),
  5     constraint fk_test_emp  foreign key (id_emp)  references emp  (empno));

Table created.

SQL> select constraint_name from user_constraints where table_name = 'TEST';

CONSTRAINT_NAME
------------------------------
FK_TEST_DEPT
FK_TEST_EMP

SQL>
```

Another *major* drawback one notices is what's written in front of the dot, here: `SYSTEM.SYS_C007167`. Yes, that would be `SYSTEM`. Shortly, don't do that. Leave SYS and SYSTEM alone; they are powerful, they are special. Why would you take the risk of destroying the database if you (un)intentionally do something hazardous? Create another user, grant required privileges and work in that schema.

If I understood you correctly, once you create that *temp* table (`TEMP_TAB7364`), its contents is transferred into the `DW_ITEMS7364` and - doing so - you hit the error.

If that's so, what's the purpose of the *temp* table? Insert directly into the target table and save resources. Will it fail? Of course it will, unless you change the query. How? I don't know - make sure that you don't insert values that don't exist in any of three tables used for enforcing referential integrity.

Though, as you already have the *temp* table, if it isn't too large, a (relatively) quick & dirty way of finding out which row is responsible for the error can be found with a loop, such as

```
begin
  for cur_r in (select col1, col2, ... from temp_table) loop
    begin
      insert into target (col1, col2, ...)
      values (cur_r.col1, cur_r.col2, ...);
    exception
      when others then 
        dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm ||': '|| cur_r.col1 ||', '||cur_r.col2);
    end;
  end loop;
end;
```

The inner `BEGIN-END` block is here to make sure that the PL/SQL code won't exit at the first error, but will display them all. Then review those values and find the reason that makes your query invalid.